# C++ Polymorphism and templated interfaces

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I'm familiar with polymorphism in general, but I'm fairly new to C++ in general and templates in particular. I have to following situation with a mixture of code that I cannot change (usage of a framework, all events and templated event listeners) and code under my control (clients in the example below).

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class EventBase {

    public:
        virtual std::string getData() const = 0;
  
};

class EventA : public EventBase {
    public:
        std::string getData() const override {
            return "Event A";
        }
};

class EventB : public EventBase {
    public:
        std::string getData() const override {
            return "Event B";
        }

};

template<class T_Event>
class IEventHandler
{
    public:
        virtual void onEvent(const T_Event& e) = 0;
        virtual void onError() = 0; 
};

class ClientBase {
    public:
        virtual void startReceiving() = 0;
        virtual void stopReceiving() {
            std::cout << "ClientBase::stopReceiving" << std::endl;
        }
};


class ClientA : public ClientBase, public IEventHandler<EventA> {
    public:
        void onEvent(const EventA& e) override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::onEvent - e.getData()= " << e.getData() << std::endl;
        };

        void onError() override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::onError" << std::endl;
        };

        void startReceiving() override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::startReceiving" << std::endl;
        };
};

class ClientB : public ClientBase, public IEventHandler<EventB> {
    public:
        void onEvent(const EventB& e) override {
            std::cout << "ClientB::onEvent - e.getData()= " << e.getData() << std::endl;
        };

        void onError() override {
            std::cout << "ClientB::onError" << std::endl;
        };

        void startReceiving() override {
            std::cout << "ClientB::startReceiving" << std::endl;
        }; 
};



int main(int, char**) {
    //User Code
    ClientA ca;
    ClientB cb;

    std::vector<ClientBase*> baseClients;
    baseClients.push_back(&ca);
    baseClients.push_back(&cb);

    for(const auto client : baseClients){
        client->startReceiving();
    }

    //Framework Code
    EventA a;
    EventB b;

    std::vector<IEventHandler<EventA>*> eventHandlersA;
    std::vector<IEventHandler<EventB>*> eventHandlersB;

    eventHandlersA.push_back(&ca);
    eventHandlersA[0]->onError();
    eventHandlersA[0]->onEvent(a);

    eventHandlersB.push_back(&cb);
    eventHandlersB[0]->onError();
    eventHandlersB[0]->onEvent(b);

    //User Code
    for(const auto client : baseClients){
        client->stopReceiving();
    }
}
```

See here: https://onlinegdb.com/2MYQhC2G5

**What I want to do now is to have a common default implementation of `onError`.**

To do so, I tried at least four approaches. Only the second worked. It would be nice to hear from C++ savants if this approach 2 is actually the way to do it.

**Approach 1**
Simply put `onError` in `ClientBase` and remove it from derived clients.

```cpp
class ClientBase {
    public:
        virtual void startReceiving() = 0;
        virtual void stopReceiving() {
            std::cout << "ClientBase::stopReceiving" << std::endl;
        }

        virtual void onError(){
            std::cout << "ClientBase::onError" << std::endl;
        }
};


class ClientA : public ClientBase, public IEventHandler<EventA> {
    public:
        void onEvent(const EventA& e) override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::onEvent - e.getData()= " << e.getData() << std::endl;
        };

        void startReceiving() override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::startReceiving" << std::endl;
        };
};
```

Fails on compile time with

```
error: variable type 'ClientA' is an abstract class
note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'onError' in 'ClientA'
```

Okay, it's abstract since it does not implement the methods needed from `IEventHandler<EventA>`

**Approach 2**
Fix the unimplemented method in `ClientA` but call the *super class method implementation*:

```
class ClientA : public ClientBase, public IEventHandler<EventA> {
    public:
        void onEvent(const EventA& e) override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::onEvent - e.getData()= " << e.getData() << std::endl;
        };

        void onError() override {
            ClientBase::onError();
        };

        void startReceiving() override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::startReceiving" << std::endl;
        };
};
```

Works, though under the hood I think other things are happening then originally intended (might be more of a *delegation* then inheritance).

Maybe mess around with templates?

**Approach 3: Remove the `IEventHandler` from the derived clients**

```cpp
class ClientBase : public IEventHandler<EventBase> {
    public:
        virtual void startReceiving() = 0;
        virtual void stopReceiving() {
            std::cout << "ClientBase::stopReceiving" << std::endl;
        }

        virtual void onError(){
            std::cout << "ClientBase::onError" << std::endl;
        }

        virtual void onEvent(const EventBase& e) = 0;
};


class ClientA : public ClientBase {
    public:
        void onEvent(const EventA& e) override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::onEvent - e.getData()= " << e.getData() << std::endl;
        };

        void startReceiving() override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::startReceiving" << std::endl;
        };
};
```

Build system hates me:

```
error: non-virtual member function marked 'override' hides virtual member function
note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'ClientBase::onEvent' declared here: type mismatch at 1st parameter ('const EventBase &' vs 'const EventA &')
error: variable type 'ClientA' is an abstract class
note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'onEvent' in 'ClientA' - virtual void onEvent(const EventBase& e) = 0;
```

Okay, so you can override methods only if the signature matches exactly.

**Approach 4: Make `ClientBase` templated**

```cpp
template<class T_Event>
class ClientBase {
    public:
        virtual void startReceiving() = 0;
        virtual void stopReceiving() {
            std::cout << "ClientBase::stopReceiving" << std::endl;
        }

        virtual void onError(){
            std::cout << "ClientBase::onError" << std::endl;
        }

        virtual void onEvent(const T_Event& e) = 0;
};


class ClientA : public ClientBase<EventA> {
    public:
        void onEvent(const EventA& e) override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::onEvent - e.getData()= " << e.getData() << std::endl;
        };

        void startReceiving() override {
            std::cout << "ClientA::startReceiving" << std::endl;
        };
};
```

Again, no success. This time my structures to track my clients would break:

```
std::vector<ClientBase*> baseClients; ----> error: use of class template 'ClientBase' requires template arguments
eventHandlersA.push_back(&ca); ---> error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
```

Do you have any more ideas on how to achieve the original goal? Or is sticking to approach 2 a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your insights into approaches 1-3 are generally correct:

- Approach 1 failed because `ClientBase` didn't inherit from `IEventHandler<>` which declared the virtual method.
- Approach 2 is indeed a delegation, which is *fine* in my opinion. Virtual methods are already a delegation - under the hood a vtable is roughly equivalent to a set of function pointers. Delegating `onError` is just one more level of indirection, and hopefully something called `onError` isn't called frequently enough to make the performance penalty significant.
- Approach 3 failed because anything overriding `onEvent(const EventBase& e)` needs to accept any `EventBase&`, per the contract.

Approach 4 failed because `ClientBase<EventA>` and `ClientBase<EventB>` are completely different types that don't share a common base. Templates are more like type factories than types - there's no relationship between instantiations.

If you want to make the this work with inheritance, you can spell out that common base explicitly by having a non-template `ClientBase` and a template layer in between to implement `onError`:

```cpp
template <typename TEvent>
class ErrorHandlingClient : public ClientBase, public IEventHandler<TEvent> {
    public:
        virtual void onError() override { /* ... */ }
};

class ClientA : public ErrorHandlingClient<EventA> {
    public:
        void onEvent(const EventA& e) override { /* ... */ }
        void startReceiving() override { /* ... */ }
};

class ClientB : public ErrorHandlingClient<EventB> { 
    public:
        void onEvent(const EventB& e) override { /* ... */ }
        void startReceiving() override { /* ... */ }
};
```

`ClientA` and `ClientB` will have different implemenations of `onError` because of the template, but they can both be casted to a common `ClientBase` type to store in a vector.

One last opinion - if you need an abstract class to get your desired code organization, it might be a sign that your concerns aren't separated: Maybe `IEventHandler<T>` should really be two interfaces, or maybe error handling should be owned by some other entity.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is having a class template with a virtual method that does not need the template parameter. It is not wrong per se, but it can easily make one's life mighty inconvenient.

The problem with your Approach 1 is having more than one *source* node in the inheritance graph that has `errorHandler`. These functions are *unrelated*. Here is a simplified demo:

```
struct X { virtual void foo() = 0; };
struct Y { virtual void foo() {} };
struct XY : X, Y {};
```

`XY` is still abstract, despite having an implementation of `foo`, because *there are two unrelated `foo`s in it* and the only way to unify them is to override `foo` *in `XY`*. This surprises a lot of people.

The best practice here (as I understand it) is moving the offending function to a common base class of `X`, `Y` and `XY` (create one if needed). Up the hierarchy, not down or sideways. It should be inherited virtually (not a diamond-of-death problem, since it is an ABC with no data members).

So don't do this:

```
template<class T_Event>
class IEventHandler
{
    public:
        virtual void onEvent(const T_Event& e) = 0;
        virtual void onError() = 0; 
};
```

Do this instead:

```
class IErrorHandler {
   public:
      virtual void onError() = 0; 
          // or whatever default implementation you want
};

template<class T_Event>
class IEventHandler : public virtual /* XXX Important! */ IErrorHandler
{
    public:
        virtual void onEvent(const T_Event& e) = 0;
};

class ClientBase : public virtual IErrorHandler {
   virtual void onError() override {} // whatever
};

class ClientA : public ClientBase, public IEventHandler<EventA> {
        virtual void onEvent(const EventA& e) {}
};
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GEKoo4oM6).

Note, the MSVC compiler may issue a warning (C4250) on this. Ignore or silence it. For your convenience, here is [a collection of SO posts on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dominance+warning).